# Filtering an array using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reducers

So I want to use Array.prototype.reduce function to reduce some array (converted from object).

This is the object which I'll later use Object.entries to get the array.

```
const activityLoading = {
  topicsForClassCourse: true,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: true,
  e: false
}
```

I also have an array of keys that I want to ignore while reducing this object. So any key that are in activityLoading as well as local it will be neglected.

```
const local = [ "topicsForClassCourse", "e" ]
```

Now I want to reduce the object into a single value. If any key is true except the one in the local array, it should return true, else false.

This is what I could come up with. But it's returning false.

```
const loadingSome = () => {
      const local = [ "topicsForClassCourse", "timetableForClass" ];
      const entries = Object.entries(activityLoading)
      
      const reducer = (acc, current) => {
        if(local.includes(current[0])) {
          return false
        }
        if(current[1]) {
          return true;
        }
        return false
      }
      
      const result = entries.reduce(reducer, false)
      console.log(result)
    }
```

https://jsbin.com/nolobupeva/edit?js,console

Comment: `reduce` is not the right function when the target is boolean, use `some` or `every`

Comment: Maybe you are right... Using some will make much more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I'd start w/ writing the test for a single value itself

```js
function test(key, value) {
  const ignore = local.includes(key)
  return !ignore && value
}
```

Once you have that, there are many ways to run it on your entire object. And I'm not sure `.reduce` is the best way to go for this. I'd suggest going for `.find`

```js
const activityLoading = {
  topicsForClassCourse: true,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: true,
  e: false
}
const local = [ "topicsForClassCourse", "e" ]

const result = Object.entries(activityLoading).find(([key, value]) => {
  const ignore = local.includes(key)
  return !ignore && value
})
console.log(result) // ['d', true]

const foundSomething = !!result
console.log(foundSomething) // true
```

And if you find it cumbersome to deal with `['d', true]` being returned, using `.some` instead of `.find` will return a boolean instead of the value that matched the test.

But if you really want to, `.reduce` could do the job too, just be careful with 2 things:

- how you initialize it (second argument). It should start at `false` because initially you assume no value matches.
- and how you accumulate (return). It should be `return accumulator || current` so that *any* `true` current will make the whole result `true`.

```js
const activityLoading = {
  topicsForClassCourse: true,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: true,
  e: false
}
const local = [ "topicsForClassCourse", "e" ]

const result = Object.entries(activityLoading).reduce((accu, [key, value]) => {
  const ignore = local.includes(key)
  const test = !ignore && value
  return accu || test
}, false)

console.log(result) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try some more simple jobs using reduce function to take it in hand. Now for your issue you can try this one:

```js
    const loadingSome = () => {
      const local = [ "topicsForClassCourse", "timetableForClass" ];
      const entries = Object.entries(activityLoading)
      
      const reducer = (acc, current) => {
        if(local.includes(current[0])) {
          return acc
        }
        return current[1] || acc;
      }
      
      const result = entries.reduce(reducer, false)
      console.log(result)
    }
```

As you see you forgot to take the `acc` into account. I have not try out the above code but it should work. If didn't let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I think your code made it much simpler for me to understand. I didn't think about using acc like that.

Answer (score 1):

How about first filter the object to filter out the `local` array keys using `filter` and then use `some` to check any key is true/false.

```js
const activityLoading = {
  topicsForClassCourse: true,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: true,
  e: false
};
const local = ["topicsForClassCourse", "e"];
let result = Object.entries(activityLoading)
  .filter(([key, value]) => !local.includes(key))
  .some(([key, value]) => value);
console.log(result);
```

or you can use only `some` array helper

```js
const activityLoading = {
  topicsForClassCourse: true,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: true,
  e: false
};
const local = ["topicsForClassCourse", "e"];
let result = Object.entries(activityLoading)
  .some(([key, value]) => !local.includes(key) && value)
console.log(result);
```